# Why is eclipse removing the navigator view?

Tags: eclipse

In the 2019-09 version of Eclipse IDE, it is showing navigator as "Navigator (Deprecated)".  Why is it going away?  Will there be a replacement?  I don't like views that hide or move actual directories around.  Sometimes I prefer to see things as they exist in version control, for testing builds, etc.

Comment: I imagine it is because it has not been updated in quite a while and there are only limited development resources available. It is still present in the current 2020-03 release.

Comment: Wait, so just because it hasn't been updated in a while, it has to be removed? The only reason to keep something is if it's been recently updated? The Navigator is an important folder-only tool which is preferred by many developers who don't like the Project Explorer.

Comment: One thing that helped me was to (under the three-dot menu) change the package and project view from "flat" to "hierarchical". It gave the project explorer view more like the nested, cleaner view of navigator. I still don't like it, there's too Java-centric of a mindset there and it's a pain to rearrange config files, etc.

Comment: Came here to ask this precise question.  How disappointing that the Eclipse folks are removing the view for no other reason than lack of code churn.

Answer (score 21):

Building off of nitind and osoblanco's suggestions:  You can make Project Explorer look exactly like the deprecated Navigator view by the following steps:

1. Click Window->Show View->Project Explorer
2. Click the three vertical dots in the top right corner of the Project Explorer Pane.
3. Click "Filters and Customization..."
4. In the "Pre-set filters" tab, uncheck "Java output folders" (thanks osoblanco for this tip)
5. In the "Content" tab, uncheck "Java Elements"

I didn't see any difference between Flat or Hierarchical in the Project presentation, so I left it as the default.
I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version 2020-09.  All of my projects use the default package, so I don't really need to see "Java Elements".

Comment: Filters is a really nice feature, but with only with this simple options does not really achieve the goal.  Maybe could be exist a pre defined configured filter to achieve navigator view with one click selection

Comment: Tip: to show folders that begin with `.`, uncheck ".* resources" under "Pre-set filters.

Answer (score 3):

I guess they figure they are supporting it well enough if you spend time configuring.  For me this gets close enough I suppose...

Hit the 3 dots in the top right.
-Set the "Package Presentation" to hierarchical.
-Alter Filters and Customization.  Uncheck "Java output folders" so that they show.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the same results with the Project Explorer view--just configure the contents to only show resources and nothing fancier.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it would be a shame to remove the "Navigator" view because it's the simplest way to get an overview with all files.
Personally I use it frequently (typically for Git) and I hope it will be kept in future versions.

However, it is true that it is also possible to do the same thing with "Project explorer" with a bit of customization. To do this, you just have to remove all filters (used to hide certain files) and select all file types to be displayed.

Here's how:

open the "**Project explorer**" view (from the main menu : Window > Show View > Project Explorer)

in the "**Project explorer**" view : open "Filters and Customization" ("funnel" icon or "3 dots" icon + "Filters and Customization" )

in "**Filters and Customization**" dialog box :

- in "**Predefined filters**": uncheck all checkboxes
- in "**User filters**" : remove all filters if any (nothing by default)
- in "**Content**" tab (used to define extensions to show) : select all available extensions (in order to show everything)

With this configuration you will see all the files located in the project (whatever the type of project, Java or other).